# How to change the state of a button when an action is completed on another screen in Xcode?

Tags: ios, uibutton, levels

How would I change the state of a button on a level select screen when a certain amount of points are achieved on the game itself?  Basically, I want to have a button to appear when a level is completed, by getting a certain amount of points, on a different screen than the game screen that I got the score on.  I want it to almost be like how it is in Angry Birds.  I have already programed the levels to open from the level select screen and from the previous level when completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable button screen is a different set of files or a different XIB, then you can call a custom `-(id)init` method to get the int or string of the score.

Something like:

```
//.h 

int passedScore;

//.m
-(id)initwithscore:(int)score { 
if (self = [super init]) {

passedScore = score;
        }
}
```

Then when you transition to the new view, call

```
[newview alloc]initwithscore://score int]autorelease];
```

Then it's a simple matter of seeing if the score is bigger or smaller than a given constant.

```
if(//scoreint >= //const) {
// do stuff 
}
```

Comment: when I enter the code you gave me into the app, it says there is an Automatic Reference Counting issue: receiver type _'new view'_ for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'initwithscore.'  What does this mean?

Comment: It means you didn't #import 'new view' @class 'new view'; and point to new view.

Comment: sorry for the questions, but I believe that I have done all that and it still shows the ARC issue.

Comment: Did you declare -(id)initwithScore:(int)score; in the .h file?

Comment: Yes, I declared the method in the .h file. I realized that you need to declare it in both files, so I did and now it says: "Expression result unused" in the same spot as before. I have the same code in both blocks except for the If - If statement in the _'newview.m'_ file and the `[newview alloc]` has the name of the other view.  I can't figure this out.  What is going on?!

Comment: You have to call "return self;" in a non-void expression.

Comment: I implemented the code into the block and it worked, but I still have the 'expression result unused' error.  What is wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5380/discussion-between-codafi-and-cory-ginsberg)